# Connect to couchDB with Javascript (Server Side)

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, couchdb, nosql

I have the following code below, where I use **Restify** to create a **node.js** server and create routes. I want to connect to CouchDB to perform GET, POST, DELETE, PUT actions.

```
  var restify = require("restify");
  var server = restify.createServer();

  server.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log("incoming requests");
  });

  server.get('/users', function(req, res){

  //CONNECT TO COUCHDB HERE

  console.log("Got it!"); 
  res.end();
  });}
```

Any idea how I can connect and retrieve my data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use nano.js or cradle.js to tap CouchDB. Or, if you prefer promises, not callbacks – use pouchdb.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery plugin to connect to CoachDB. You can look through the below links to get more details
http://www.couchbase.org/community/articles/couchdb/recipes/3
http://java.dzone.com/news/couchdb-jquery-plugin

Comment: This plugin is not compatible with node.js.

Comment: @ermouth Ive been trying to make this work for ages. Thank you for clearing this for me. Now I why it isn't working. Do you have another solution to the issue?